# Avoiding C++ virtual inheritance

Tags: c++

I'm trying to inherit from a hierarchy of abstract base classes, using an equivalent hierarchies of implementation classes. The only way I've figured out how to do it is using virtual inheritance.

```
/* Foo Interface */
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    virtual ~IFoo() = default;
};

/* Bar Interface */
class IBar : virtual public IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    virtual ~IBar() = default;
};

/* A specialized Foo */
class SpecificFoo : virtual public IFoo
{
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
};

/* A specialized Bar */
class SpecificBar : virtual public IBar, virtual public SpecificFoo
{
public:
    void bar() override { std::cout << "Bar!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    SpecificBar b;

    b.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Although I'm not entirely opposed to using virtual inheritance, I'm not sure that it's the correct approach. Having to use dynamic_cast seems like something to avoid if possible. Is there a better way to do this?

I've tried something with an adapter pattern, but copy/pasting wrapper methods is getting out of hand.

Comment: Do you have a reason to avoid virtual inheritance?  Yes it has some (minor) runtime cost, like virtual functions in general, but if you want to implement more than one interface, you need it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I don't have any strong reason to avoid it, no. It feels like the compiler should be able to figure the above example out at compile time, rather than dynamically at run time, and it makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: In the example above, there's nothing dynamic and the method call will almost certainly be resolved statically (at compile time) by any reasonable compiler.  If you declare `SpecificBar` or `SpecificBar::bar` as `final` many more cases will be resolvable statically, but in all cases the virtual inheritance is completely irrelevant -- the only dynamic behavior here comes from the virtual methods.

Comment: Interesting. I was trying to find information about devirtualization with virtual inheritance, but I was seeing mixed results. In any case, I'd mostly be passing around an `IBar*` to hide implementation details.

Comment: Passing around an `IBar *` means you'll need a dynamic function call (generally one extra memory acces and an indirect branch) to call the method.  This is the cost of the `virtual` on the method; using `virtual` base classes is irrelevant.  The main issue with virtual bases is that they need to be constructed by the 'outermost' constructor when constructing a new object, so they pretty much need to have just a default (0 arg) ctor, possibly a copy and/or move ctor, and no other ctors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that avoids virtual inheritance, but also gets rid of code duplication. I used a template parameter to specify the base class.

```cpp
/* Foo Interface */
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    virtual ~IFoo() = default;
};

/* Bar Interface */
class IBar : public IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    virtual ~IBar() = default;
};

/* A specialized Foo */
template <typename _BaseClass>
class SpecificFooTpl : public _BaseClass
{
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
};

using SpecificFoo = SpecificFooTpl<IFoo>;

/* A specialized Bar */
class SpecificBar : public SpecificFooTpl<IBar>
{
public:
    void bar() override { std::cout << "Bar!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    SpecificFoo f;
    SpecificBar b;

    f.foo();
    b.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the benefit of making `IBar` a sub-type of `IFoo` from the posted code.
IMO, it will be better to remove that inheritance.

```
/* Foo Interface */
class IFoo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;

    virtual ~IFoo() = default;
};

/* Bar Interface */
class IBar 
{
  public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    virtual ~IBar() = default;
};

/* A specialized Foo */
class SpecificFoo : public IFoo
{
  public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
};

/* A specialized Bar */
class SpecificBar : public IBar
{
  public:
    void bar() override { std::cout << "Bar!\n"; }
};

/* A specialized Foo and Bar */
class SpecificFooAndBar : public IFoo, public IBar
{
  public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
    void bar() override { std::cout << "Bar!\n"; }
};
```

Comment: It's kind of a trivial example, but the benefit would be that I could call foo() from an IBar pointer without casting it to a specialized type.

Comment: @Stephen, that seems to be an unclean strategy to me. It's not something I would recommend. The interfaces `IFoo` and `IBar` are independent of each other and sholud be kept that way.

Comment: `SpecificFooAndBar` might have members `SpecificFoo`/`SpecificBar` as member to avoid repetition of `bar`/`foo` implementation by forwarding those to the members.